# WinRM service fails to listen when configured via group policy

Tags: group-policy, winrm

From Powershell, running

```
Get-WSManInstance winrm/config/listener -Enumerate
```

Produces standard output, including;

```
source: GPO
Transport: HTTP
Port: 5985 
ListeningOn: null
```

The service is running.
Yet, somehow, in cmd:

```
netstat -aon | find "5985"
```

Produces no output at all. No programs actually listen on 5985. Thus testing winRM;

```
test-wsman 127.0.0.1
```

Produces 'canot connect to destination' errors.

Yes, the IPv4Filter and IPv6Filter have been configured to `*` for the policy that enables winRM, and this is the only policy that defines anything in the winRM folder. It's being applied (verified via `GPResult`).

Answer (score 3):

The `null` here for `ListeningOn` is the hint. While the listener exists, it does not open any ports because no interfaces match the `IPv4Filter`, which is set to the empty string, `''`. The GPO to enable the IPv4Filter and IPv6Filter for WinRM at `Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Remote Management -> WinRM Service --> Allow remote server management through WinRM`, necessary to make WinRM listen to traffic and accept incoming connections sometimes plain *will not do anything*; the filters defined there are not used by the service.

Instead, manually modify the registry (via GPO) by setting the keys:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WinRM\Service\IPv4Filter = *
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WinRM\Service\IPv6Filter = *
```

Both are of type `REG_SZ`. If you only want WinRM to listen on one interface, set the filter to the network used on that interface; e.g. `192.168.1.1-192.168.1.255`